# Advice regarding Wallet application

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am going to make a wallet application in mobile that has following features:

- Add money (User can add money to wallet via net banking, debit/credit card)
- Cash out (money will transfer from wallet to user's bank)
- Transfer money (User can transfer money in the wallet from one user to another user)

I want your precious advice on which payment gateway to use to fulfill my requirement.

The application will be based in India but anyone can use it all over the world.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Flutterwave](http://flutterwave.com). You can use them for your wallet based solution. They will also work for transfers to Ghana, Kenya and Nigeria. They are more focused on Africa, so they should cover the whole of Africa very soon. TransferWise currently uses them for remittance to Nigeria and Kenya. See Article [Here](https://www.businessdayonline.com/transferwise-make-pound-naira-transfer-20-cheaper/)